# How to integrate a multivariate function in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-integration

How do I integrate something like `(x + y)` (or an expression with **any number** of variables) with respect to **just one** of the variables, let's say `x` from `0` to `1`, and get a **function** of the other variable (`1/2 + y` in this case) back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean symbolically, then use:

```
syms x y
f=int(x+y,x,0,1)
```

which gives

```
f =
y + 1/2
```

then get `f(y=4)` from `subs(f,4)` which gives

```
ans =
9/2
```

If you have more than two variables, use:

```
syms x y z
f=int(x+y+z,x,0,1)
```

which gives

```
f =
y + z + 1/2
```

then for `f(y=4,z=5)` use `subs(f,{y,z},[4,5])` gives

```
ans =
19/2
```

Comment: how come this doesn't work? %syms xi xf % zi = 0 % zf = 1 % d = sqrt((xf - xi).^2 + (zf - zi)^2); %
Efield = int(exp(-1i* k *d)./d,xi,-0.1,0.1) ... it doesn't integrate over xi :(

Comment: Post it as a new question with a self-contained example (e.g. have you done `syms k` as well?). I suspect the answer is that Matlab can't integrate that function analytically - it doesn't look easy, but changing the coordinates may help (e.g. polar coordinates in the $x,z$ plane). It may be better to ignore Matlab for now and post the question as an integration problem on http://math.stackexchange.com: they will use a symbolic package if they have to. Try to give some background to the problem, e.g. "I'm trying to calculate the electric field of a piece of wire ..."